# Exceeded myopia limit on UK CAA Class 1 Medical, am I still eligible?

Tags: medical, airline-pilot, caa-uk-regulations, uk

I am 17 and this may sound stupid but my vision in my left eye is -4.50, and my right eye is -7. My right eye exceeds the limit of -6 by just 1, I am following off the UK CAA guidelines as I hope to become an airline pilot in the UK. Does the fact that my eye misses the limit by -1 completely erase my chances of becoming a pilot? I have contacted various aeromedical centres regarding this too. But I would also like to hear from other  pilots who are in a similar situation.

Comment: Are you correctable to 20/20 with glasses?

Comment: Consider this: If your navigation is off by just 1 degree, over a long enough distance, you'll end up at the wrong airport (or at no airport at all). Just because you're "really close", doesn't mean it's acceptable. Though, as @JohnK asked, I believe the question is what is your corrected vision, not uncorrected vision.

Comment: Nobody actually flies that way in the real world.  The standard for a pilot holding a heading is +/-5 deg, and wet compasses can be off by up to 10 and be legal.

Comment: Yes my vision can easily be corrected to 20/20 with contact lenses or glasses.

Comment: You are evaluated on corrected vision, not raw.